# JS not allow dashes (-); any ideas?

Tags: json, dojo, getjson

I have a fieldname on the database called CONTEST with the following values:

```
50 - DE - HOUSE 5 -D
47 - SHERIFF - M
```

There are several lines of those.

The fieldname is a text field.

I use the following JavaScript to try to display these values on a table:

```
//Create list of available contest to display.
function CreateResultSet(featureSet) {
    demVoteCount = 0;
    repVoteCount = 0;
    otherVoteCount = 0;
    RemoveChildren(dojo.byId("race"));
    resultsDataGroup = new Object();
    var controlIndex = 0;
    if (featureSet.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.length; i++) {
            if (!resultsDataGroup[featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST]) {
                resultsDataGroup[featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST] = new Array();
                var divRaceData = document.createElement("div");
                divRaceData.className = "divData";
                divRaceData.id = "divRaceName" + (controlIndex);
                divRaceData.innerHTML = featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST;
                divRaceData.setAttribute("controlIndex", controlIndex);
                divRaceData.onclick = function () { DisplayChart(this); };
                dojo.byId("race").appendChild(divRaceData);
                controlIndex++;
            }

            if (featureSet[i].attributes.PARTY == "DEM") {
                demVoteCount += featureSet[i].attributes.VOTES;
            }
            else if (featureSet[i].attributes.PARTY == "REP") {
                repVoteCount += featureSet[i].attributes.VOTES;
            }
            else {
                otherVoteCount += featureSet[i].attributes.VOTES;
            }
            resultsDataGroup[featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST].push({ ContestName: featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST, CandidateName: featureSet[i].attributes.CANDIDATE, VoteTotal: featureSet[i].attributes.VOTES, Party: featureSet[i].attributes.PARTY });
        }
        dojo.byId("race").scrollTop = 0;
        currentRaceIndex = 0;
        DisplayChart(dojo.byId("race").childNodes[0]);
        dojo.byId('divSelectedGeometry').innerHTML = dojo.query(".divSelectedGeo", dojo.byId('geometry'))[0].innerHTML + " - ";
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I am getting "CONTEST" not found.

However, if I remove the dashes, the results display correctly but the dashes need to be there.

Any idea how to modify the so the fieldname called CONTEST to account for the dashes?

Sorry in advance if this is poorly worded.

Thanks alot

Comment: could you run firebug or chrome developer tools and tell us at which line does the error happen. this could help you get to the cause of the problem

Comment: @kabaros, it is on this line:

divRaceData.innerHTML = featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST;

Comment: The code shouldn't fail providing the property `.CONTEST` exists and is a legal javascript identifier. The error message indicates that `.CONTEST` does not exist, so I can only assume that the problem lies somewhere outside the code posted; ie wherever `featureSet` is composed.

Comment: I am sorry @Beetroot, I think it is here where it is being used as a WHERE clause.

    query.where = "CONTEST = '" + control.innerHTML + "' and " + electionResutlsConfig[cResultIndex].idField + " is not null";

I am new to thtis. Please forgive me. In SQL Server CONTEST would be wrapped in [...] like [CONTEST].I am not sure how it is used in json.

Comment: Yes, I agree it could indeed be an SQL issue. Unless there's something about Dojo that I don't understand, you appear to compose the SQL in javascript and send it to the server to be executed, right? This is generally considered bad practice for a number of reasons, chiefly security - you reveal too much to attackers. It's better to send a minimum amount of data to the sever (as part of a GET or POST request) and compose the SQL there, in response to the data.

Comment: Thank you @Beetroot-Beetroot, I understand. I inherited this app and their accompanying codes unfortunately.

Is there a way though to encase the WHERE clause to work with values with hyphen and spaces as shown above?

Comment: Chidi, I expect so but I'm not too hot on SQL and all my experience is in mySQL anyway. Hopefully someone else with the appropriate knowledge will come by. If not, then you will need to ask a new question with tags appropriate to where you now know the problem to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way for sql to have dashes is just to put it between brackets which you are doing, so dashes shouldn't be breaking your sql.

The only explanation I have is that your object is missing some values when coming from server-side.

Could you change the line where the error happen to add some extra checks so:

```
divRaceData.innerHTML = (featureSet[i] && featureSet[i].attributes && featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST)?featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST : "VALUE MISSING";
```

If you get "VALUE MISSING" then there is something wrong in your server-side code and one or more object don't have the hierarchy you're expecting.

And like Beetroot said in the comments, it's a very bad practice to inject SQL like this so even if you inherited the applicaiton, it's well worth changing that

Comment: Thank you @Kabaros. I did as you suggested but I don't get VALUE MISSING message. I do have something like "Unable to find CONTEST" and I know this exists.

Comment: try changing to  featureSet[i].attributes[CONTEST] .. and also have firebug or console open, and add a line: console.log( featureSet[i].attributes.CONTEST); in your code before this call and look at the object that you get if it is formed the way you expect it

Comment: I used firebug. After making latest change you suggested, it still shows same error

Comment: could you just do console.log(featureSet) or just get your featureSet object somehow and share it with us?

Comment: I will be glad to share whatever you want; I really need to get this working.

How do you do console.log(featureSet)?

Comment: just anywhere in your code, add this line: console.log(featureSet) then look at the console in firebug and it should have logged the object and you can look at it yourself ... and to share it with us, you can add this line instead which will produce a string out of the object: console.log(JSON.stringify(featureSet)) and share the output with us

Comment: I am very sorry @Kabaros. I was called into a meeting which scared the $#$$ out of me. It turned out that they discovered the issue.

The issue is that there are a bunch of $$ between each value. Plus additional empty space. For instance, instead of Kabaros, you either get spaceKabaros or Kabarosspace. Not the word but space as in ' '. Can this query below be modified to handle the space either before or after value?

 WHERE clause. query.where = "CONTEST = '" + control.innerHTML + "' and " + electionResutlsConfig[cResultIndex].idField + " is not null";